# Creating samba users as system users

Tags: users, samba

I want to provide access to my machine to a couple of colleagues;

However I want these 2 users to be able to access **only** my shamba share;

Is it considered a good practice to add them as system users via

```
adduser --system --no-create-home <username>
```

so as to prevent login and home dir creation

and then create their samba passwords via

```
sudo smbpasswd -a
```

?

Comment: Yes. I think what you have described is a good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want them to access samba shares then all you need is:

```
useradd smbuser
smbpasswd -a smbuser
```

You then edit your smb.conf to include the users and then give them permissions for the shares via `chmod` and/or `chown`. The users will be able to access the samba shares but they won't be able to log into the machine directly or via `ssh` as the password will only authenticate for `samba`.

This how I do it with `Centos 7.5` and `samba 4.7.1`. I've been doing it this way for many years since `Centos 5` and earlier versions of `samba`.